# Installation of Google Stenographer and its directory access requirements

Tags: software-installation, permissions

I'm hoping someone could answer what I'm sure is a basic question about the Ubuntu/Linux directory structure.  I am trying to get Google Stenographer installed/configured on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS box.  The instructions I am following (https://github.com/google/stenographer/blob/master/INSTALL.md) state the following:

There are a few directories Stenographer needs in order to run correctly:

/etc/stenographer root:root/0755
/etc/stenographer/certs stenographer:stenographer/0750

My question is, can someone please describe to me what is meant by the "root:root/0755" and "stenographer:stenographer/0750" portions of those lines?

The information I've been able to find leads me to think they are related to group/user/permission levels perhaps???  And if so, what do the 0755 and 0750 indicate?

Thank you!
Jeff S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of access in a standard Linux filesystem (of which there are many):

> read: the file can be only read  (sometimes noted as **R**)
>   write: the file can be edited  (sometimes noted as **W**)
>   execute: the file can be run as a program  (sometimes noted as **X**)

There are three types of user groups these access types can be applied to:

> owner: the owner of the file
>   group: other files which are in the same folder or group
>   world: anyone else

The access level is defined in numbers:

> 0 - no access to the file
>   1 - execute only
>   2 - write only
>   3 - write and execute
>   4 - read only
>   5 - read and execute
>   6 - read and write
>   7 - read, write and execute (full permissions)

*/etc/stenographer root:root/0755* means
/etc/stenographer is owned by root,
members of the root group can read and execute,
and other users can read and execute.

*/etc/stenographer/certs stenographer:stenographer/0750* means
/etc/stenographer/certs is owned by stenographer,
members of the stenographer group can read and execute,
but other users have no access.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much, K7AAY.